# How do i convert videos uploaded by user to .swf?

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I am creating a website which enables to upload videos. But we know that user can upload any kind of video but the browser can't play them. So, I thought that I somehow can convert them into .swf and play them using a flash player. I tried to use ffmpeg-php but it didn't worked. my code was:

```
shell_exec('ffmpeg -i in.mp4 out.swf');
```

It does not show any error neither it returns `out.swf`.

**Please! help me.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Things to check:

1. Does the `in.mp4` file actually exist on the server and is it in the
   correct temporary folder?
2. Check that file size limits (`upload_max_filesize` PHP setting) are
   not being hit.
3. Does the `ffmpeg` command work properly from a shell promt **as the
   user that the webserver is running as**? *(this test should be
   performed in the folder where you are processing the file)* Use the
   verbose logging options to check for errors
4. Capture all the output from the `shell_exec` and check for errors.
   Try using `system` or `exec` where you can also capture the return
   value of `ffmpeg` which can then be used for error checking

Finally, I would specify actual directory names for the input and output files. This will narrow down problems as you know *exactly* what folder to look in for results. You can also adjust permissions if required

Comment: but i could not get the quality of image same as the input file. could you help me with that too. :)

Comment: i forget to place a '&' in my code which didn't executed the command i had to place it over ".. out.swf &');"

Comment: You'll never get the same quality out as you feed in. The video compression systems which (both in and out) are in use here are both lossy. You may be able to get better output via options passed to `ffmpeg` but this will increase the size of the resultant file